# ListPopupWindow not obeying WRAP_CONTENT width spec

Tags: android, user-interface, popupwindow

I'm trying to use ListPopupWindow to show a list of strings via an `ArrayAdapter` (eventually this will be a more complex custom adapter). Code is below. As shown in the screenshot, the resulting `ListPopupWindow` seems to act as if the content width is zero. It shows the proper number of items, the items are still clickable, and clicking successfully produce a `Toast`, so at least that much is working properly.

An interesting note: I could supply a width in pixels to `popup.setWidth(...)` instead of `ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT` and it will show some of the content, but this seems very inflexible.

How do I make the `ListPopupWindow` wrap its content?

**Test activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String[] STRINGS = {"Option1","Option2","Option3","Option4"};
    private View anchorView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        anchorView = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                showPopup();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void showPopup() {
        ListPopupWindow popup = new ListPopupWindow(this);
        popup.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, STRINGS));
        popup.setAnchorView(anchorView);
        popup.setWidth(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
        popup.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        popup.show();
    }
}
```

**screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: It seems that using `WRAP_CONTENT` causes the popup to set its width equal to the width of the anchor view, which in this example is the home icon on the ActionBar. I may end up having to use an explicit width value...

Comment: Can you do setContentWidth to WRAP_CONTENT instead of setWidth? I can't test this right now so I am not going to put it as an answer yet

Comment: @Mike: That doesn't help unfortunately. I checked the source code, and setContentWidth() forwards the call to setWidth(). The only difference is it accounts for some padding of the background drawable.

Comment: I did it like this and it works. I'm using this inside adapter .  View view = ((AppCompatActivity) context).findViewById(R.id.sortItems); sortItems is the menu view on the Toolbar(Contextual actionBar).  listPopupWindow.setWidth(view.getWidth() * 6);
                    listPopupWindow.show(); Would definetly works

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problem is with the implementation of `ListPopupWindow`. I checked the source code, and using `setContentWidth(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT)` or `setWidth(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT)` makes the popup window use the width of its anchor view instead.

Comment: Did the different layout in the ArrayAdapter not do anything then? I feel like there should be some way that this can be corrected

Comment: Hmm, this seems like a common use case, that is unfortunate :(

Comment: @Karakuri Did you ever find a nice workaround for this? It looks like it is still not fixed and its frustrating to say the least.

Comment: You've misunderstood. There is no way to make the ListPopupWindow obey the `WRAP_CONTENT` width spec. I am pointing out this fact by explaining that the source code sets the width of the ListPopupWindow to the width of the anchor view when you use `WRAP_CONTENT`.

Comment: I used `PopupMenu`. Works fine, although it works with XML only, and with API 11+. Please refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23550266/1276636

Answer (score 66):

You could measure the width of the adapter content:

```
private int measureContentWidth(ListAdapter listAdapter) {
    ViewGroup mMeasureParent = null;
    int maxWidth = 0;
    View itemView = null;
    int itemType = 0;

    final ListAdapter adapter = listAdapter;
    final int widthMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    final int heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    final int count = adapter.getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        final int positionType = adapter.getItemViewType(i);
        if (positionType != itemType) {
            itemType = positionType;
            itemView = null;
        }

        if (mMeasureParent == null) {
            mMeasureParent = new FrameLayout(mContext);
        }

        itemView = adapter.getView(i, itemView, mMeasureParent);
        itemView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        final int itemWidth = itemView.getMeasuredWidth();

        if (itemWidth > maxWidth) {
            maxWidth = itemWidth;
        }
    }

    return maxWidth;
}
```

and in your showPopup() function:

```
 ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, STRINGS);
    popup.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    popup.setAnchorView(anchorView);
    popup.setContentWidth(measureContentWidth(arrayAdapter));
```

Comment: Nice. I only added mMeasureParent initialization and voted up.

Comment: Got a crash on layout with sole TextView. Had to add
`if (itemView != null && itemView.getLayoutParams() == null) {
                itemView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            }`

Comment: I think the solution isn't working, I'm getting the wrong width back and the content looks cut out ... strange

Answer (score 7):

I think the best thing to use is the PopupMenu . example:

```
final PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mActivity, v);
popupMenu.getMenu().add("test");
popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(final MenuItem item) {
        return true;
    }
});
popupMenu.show();
```

Comment: Yes, but only if you don't need some custom content for menu items

Comment: What do you mean? all menu items are customized - you always choose which string to set...

Comment: @android_developer unless you want it to be a custom view

Comment: @DenisKniazhev Oh, you mean the opposite of what I thought. You mean you wish a totally customized popup? but here they wanted a list of items, so it should suffice.

Answer (score 5):

I would just set a dimension in your dimen.xml file at 160dp or so:

```
<dimen name="overflow_width">160dp</dimen>
```

Then set your popup width using the getDimensionPixelSize method to convert into pixels:

```
int width = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.overflow_width); 
mListPopupWindow.setWidth(width);
```

That should keep the size density independent.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that your issue lies with your ArrayAdapter using simple_list_item_1. If you look at the source code for that element it has the property of

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

If you look at the source [here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) you can create your own new_list_item_1.xml with the same info but changing it to `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` and then use that in your ArrayAdapter

Comment: it didn't work for me. sure you aren't missing anything?

Answer (score 3):

You can actually get the anchorView's parent (since the actual anchorView is generally a button) and base your width from there. For example:

```
popup.setWidth(((View)anchor.getParent()).getWidth()/2);
```

That way you can get a flexible width.

Comment: This doesn't help. The problem is I want to respect the size of the popup window contents, which is what the WRAP_CONTENT width spec is supposed to do, even according to Google's documentation. This has no relation whatsoever to the width of the anchor view or its parent view.

Comment: @Karakuri actually, google talked about this issue a long time ago, in a lecture called "the world of listView". they said there that you can't use wrap_content, as you can't really expect it to check all of the items (there could be a huge number of items). same goes for both height and width. they also said that if you use it for height, they do something weird (I don't remember what, maybe taking  3 items and that's it or something similar) .

Comment: @androiddeveloper Yes, they did talk about it. But `ListPopupWindow` was introduced in API 11, well after they knew of the issue with `ListView`. I'm referring to the documentation of `ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT` (not `ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT`), which states: "If used to specify a popup width, the popup will use the width of its content." If this value is never obeyed by ListView, their inclusion of it as a public API with that documentation is erroneous and misleading.

Comment: @Karakuri Well since the content is a listView, and its width isn't determined by its content like other views do, you need to set it yourself...

Answer (score 1):

The following can help;

```
listPopupWindow.setWidth(400);
listPopupWindow.setHeight(ListPopupWindow.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to set a 0dp height view in your layout xml to use as an anchor.

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/popup_anchor"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

then set the anchor view sometime before calling the show() method.

```
listPopupWindow.setAnchorView(popupAnchor);
listPopupWindow.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this.

Create a `View`in your layout which functions as an anchor, with your dedicated width and position (Height 1 dp, width as you wish) (may be dynamic i.e. with ConstraintLayouts). Make it invisible (`android:visibility=View.INIVISIBLE`).

```
                <View
                    android:id="@+id/my_anchor"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/list_item_order_list_app_compat_image_button_gallery"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/list_item_order_list_material_button_map"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    android:visibility="invisible"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    />
```

Reference to this view in your `viewAnchor`, (i.e with bindings):

`listPopupWindow.anchorView = binding.myAnchor`

Answer (score 0):

I used the following Kotlin function to measure the max width from adapter items and then set it to the popup width, and it's working fine:

```kotlin
/**
* Put this inside your adapter class
*/
fun measureMaxItemWidth(): Int {
    return (0 until count)
        .mapNotNull { getView(it, null, null)?.apply {
            measure(View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
        } }
        .maxByOrNull { it.measuredWidth }
        ?.measuredWidth ?: 0
}

You can use it as follows:

private val popupWindow: ListPopupWindow = ListPopupWindow(context).apply {
    anchorView = yourAnchorView
    setAdapter(menuAdapter)
    setOnDismissListener {
        // Your dismiss listener logic here
    }
    setContentWidth(menuAdapter.measureMaxItemWidth())
}
```